# Java: insert element in the middle of custom made generic vector

Tags: java, generics, vector

I am trying to write a code to insert a string/integer/null to the middle of a generic vector in JAVA. But this part of code doesn't compile. What might be the problem? Thank you. I'm also adding error messages.

```
public synchronized void addToPosition (T element, int index) {
    if (index+1 == size-1) {
        ensureCapacity();
    }
    System.out.println("Add element to position:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    index = scanner.nextInt();
    if (index < 0 || index > this.index-1) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    T[] newElementData = (T[]) new Object [size];
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        newElementData[i] = elementData[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Which element to add?");
    element = (T) scanner.nextLine();
    newElementData[index] = element;
    for (i = index+1; i < this.index; i++) {
        newElementData[i] = elementData[i+1];
    }
    elementData = newElementData;
    this.index++;
}
```

[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIUrW.png)

Comment: Doesn't look like the error is here. It's in the code calling this method.

Comment: I'm calling this method in main function: MyVector<Integer> vectorList = new MyVector<>(); vectorList.addToPosition();

Comment: ...your signature is also (mostly) ignored, because you use the console to add the element _inside_ the method, instead of passing them in from outside (as would normally be expected).  It looks like you have code from other methods inside this (specifically, `ensureCapacity()`), as well as code that belongs in whatever is calling this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in the comments, you call the `addToPosition()` method like so:

```
vectorList.addToPosition();
```

while the method signature is the following:

```
public synchronized void addToPosition (T element, int index) {
```

So they don't match. For example, you can get rid of the parameters:

```
public synchronized void addToPosition () {
    T element;  // the values you will read later from user input
    int index;
```

Comment: Now that was a stupid mistake. Thank you, I see this code still has many problems, but I will deal with it.